# My binary search on java doesn't count or print the right index values after the search

Tags: java, search, binary-search

I am programming a class that when called upon, would search for a specific number using binary search. The program would also print the number of times it searched for a said number, and return the index value. Unfortunately, the index value always returns me a -1, which is the number I set it as when the value does not exist from the array. The array is scanned from a text file containing the numbers 1-131073

Anyways the code looks like this:

```
 public static int binarySearch(int[] elements, int target)
    {
        int index = -1;
        int count = 0;
        int low = 0;
        int high = elements.length-1;
        int mid;  

  while(high>=low)
        {
            count++;
            mid = (low+high)/2;
            if(target < elements[mid]) 
            {
                high = mid - 1;
            }
             else if(target > elements[mid])
            {
                low = mid + 1;
            }
             else //if (target == elements[mid])
             {
                index = mid;
                break;
            } 
        }
        System.out.println(count);
        return index;
    }
```

Even when the last if else statement doesn't have the 2 backslashes, it doesn't affect the index number.

EDIT
Ok So as it would turn out, the actual code for my binary search isn't perfect, but that isn't the issue, the issue was my actual tester. I had it reading strings instead of reading numbers

Comment: Are you sure the `elements` array is sorted?

Comment: Run your code step-by-step under debugger and inspect the relevant values along the way.

Comment: It is sorted correctly Henry

Comment: Is the target value actually in the array?

Comment: I have checked to be sure, and yes David, the value is on the array

Comment: I just edited my post, but it turns out it was human error all along. My binary search still doesn't work 100%, but it searches for numbers a whole lot better now